# Why would the replace with regex not work even though the regex does?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

There may be a very simple answer to this, probably because of my familiarity (or possibly lack thereof) of the replace method and how it works with regex.

Let's say I have the following string: `abcdefHellowxyz`

I just want to strip the first six characters and the last four, to return `Hello`, using regex... Yes, I know there may be other ways, but I'm trying to explore the boundaries of what these methods are capable of doing...

Anyway, I've tinkered on http://regex101.com and got the following Regex worked out:

`/^(.{6}).+(.{4})$/`

Which seems to pass the string well and shows that `abcdef` is captured as group 1, and `wxyz` captured as group 2. But when I try to run the following:

`"abcdefHellowxyz".replace(/^(.{6}).+(.{4})$/,"")`

to replace those captured groups with "" I receive an empty string as my final output... Am I doing something wrong with this syntax? And if so, how does one correct it, keeping my original stance on wanting to use Regex in this manner...

Thanks so much everyone in advance...

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace as guide

Comment: you want `"abcdefHellowxyz".replace(/^(.{6})(.+)(.{4})$/,"$2")` - because that's how replace works ... or `"abcdefHellowxyz".replace(/^.{6}(.+).{4}$/,"$1")` - because you don't really need to capture discarded content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing any substring that matches `/^(.{6}).+(.{4})$/`, with this line of code:

```
"abcdefHellowxyz".replace(/^(.{6}).+(.{4})$/,"")
```

The regex matches the whole string `"abcdefHellowxyz"`; thus, the whole string is replaced. Instead, if you are strictly stripping by the lengths of the extraneous substrings, you could simply use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) or [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

---

### Edit

The answer you're probably looking for is capturing the middle token, instead of the outer ones:

```js
var str = "abcdefHellowxyz";
var matches = str.match(/^.{6}(.+).{4}$/);
str = matches[1];  // index 0 is entire match
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense... so in other words if I want to keep to the idea of replacements with regex in a similar manner, it would have to be... I'm guessing `"abcdefHellowxyz".replace(/^(.{6})/,"").replace(/(.{4})$/,"")` ...?

Just tested it... that works... thanks for clearing it up... and here I was thinking the groupings only would be affected... Silly me.

Answer (score 2):

The code below works well as you wish

```
"abcdefHellowxyz".replace(/^.{6}(.+).{4}$/,"$1")
```

I think that only use `()`to capture the text you want, and in the second parameter of `replace()`, you can use `$1` `$2` ... to represent the `group1` `group2`. 
Also you can pass a function to the second parameter of `replace`,and transform the captured text to whatever you want in this function.

For more detail, as @Akxe recommend , you can find document on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace.

Comment: That makes for a quicker code... Thank you both for your assistance!